# Hashing array of strings as Merkle tree in one function

Tags: java, hash-map, hashcode

I want to hash an array of strings into one hash as shown on scheme on the image below. But I do not want to implement some class based Merkle tree. It's just a simple function. Is this a good implementation or are there any possible improvements?

[image]

```
public static String hashStrings(@NotNull String [] strs)
{
    if (strs.length == 1) return hashString(strs[0]);

    List<String> hashes = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++)
    {
        hashes.add(hashString(strs[i]));
    }

    while(hashes.size() > 1)
    {
        int currentSize = hashes.size();
        int nextSize = currentSize % 2 == 0 ? currentSize / 2 : (currentSize + 1) / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < currentSize - 1; i += 2)
        {
            hashes.set(i / 2, hashString(hashes.get(i) + hashes.get(i + 1)));
        }

        if (currentSize % 2 == 1)
        {
            hashes.set(nextSize - 1, hashString(hashes.get(currentSize - 1)));
        }

        hashes = hashes.subList(0, nextSize);
    }

    return hashes.get(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this statement is quite complicated to read, compared to what you want achieve:

```
int nextSize = currentSize % 2 == 0 ? currentSize / 2 : (currentSize + 1) / 2;
```

You could consider using some brackets:

```
int nextSize = (currentSize % 2 == 0) ? (currentSize / 2) : ((currentSize + 1) / 2);
```

Or just use [Math.ceil()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)):

```
int nextSize = (int) Math.ceil(currentSize / 2.0))
```

Furthermore you are computing `hashes.size()` twice per loop:

```
while(hashes.size() > 1)
{
    int currentSize = hashes.size();
    // ...
```

you could write:

```
int currentSize = hashes.size();
while(currentSize > 1)
{
    currentSize = hashes.size();
    // ....
```

instead.

Other than that your code looks fine to me, besides `strs` is not the best name for a parameter. You could rename it to improve readability and usability.